# write latexmk command line options in latexmkrc

Tags: latexmk

Is there a way to write arbitary `latexmk` command line options into the `latexmkrc` file?

For example, I think that instead of calling

```
latexmk -pdf -halt-on-error file.tex
```

I can put

```
$pdf_mode = 1
$pdflatex = ’pdflatex -halt-on-error %O %S’
```

in the `latexmkrc` file.

But this only works for `pdflatex`, so if I switch to `lualatex`, I have to
add the following.

```
$lualatex = ’lualatex -halt-on-error %O %S’
```

Now to solve this problem apparently there is a way to specify options for all latex compilers:

```
set_tex_cmds( '-halt-on-error %O %S' );
```

but this still involves some thinking since I have to recognize a command line option as one that is passed through to the tex compiler.

Isn't there a way to simply write `latexmk` command line options in the config file to have the same effect?

(I'm asking since I was trying to copy command line options from vscode latex-workshop config to `latexmkrc`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing of this kind is currently implemented in latexmk.

However, although that statement is true of the the latexmk code itself, there is a way of achieving what you want.  The trick is to notice that Perl puts the command line arguments in an array `@ARGV` and that latexmk processes the latexmkrc files before the command line. A latexmkrc file can modify `@ARGV`.

To prepend the options `-pdf` and `-halt-on-error` to the command line, you can do

```
unshift @ARGV, '-pdf', '-halt-on-error';
```

These options are processed after the latexmkrc files are processed, but before the options on the actual command line.

If you want the extra options to be processed after the options on the command line (e.g., to override them), you replace `unshift` by `push`.

Comment: Great! So would I put that at the beginning or the end of the `latexmkrc` file, or doesn't that matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter:  Latexmk uses the contents of `@ARGV` only after it has executed the code in the `latexmkrc` files.